# How can you display MySQL BLOB Images in a Xamarin Imageview?

Tags: android, mysql, xamarin, bitmap, imageview

I have converted my imageview to a bitmap and then to a byte array.

```
Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)ivTest.Drawable).Bitmap;

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
            byte[] bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
```

What I want to do is fetch this BLOB image and display it in another ImageView. Can I do this by using an SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I have written in C# to do this (it is from a web api method)

```
 public void viewLatestImageUpload(int imageType)
    {
        Context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Stream strm = ShowAlbumImage(imageType);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 8192);
        while (byteSeq > 0)
        {
            Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
            byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 8192);
        }
    }
```

Here is the method that pulls image from database:

```
public Stream ShowAlbumImage(int imageType)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = getEtechConnection();
        string sql;
        if (imageType == 1)
        {
            sql = "SELECT TOP 1 Img_stream from EquipmentImages ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC";
        }
        else
        {
            sql = "SELECT TOP 1 Receipt from ETechReceiptImg ORDER BY StrtDate DESC, StrtTime DESC";
        }
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        myConnection.Open();
        object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        try
        {
            return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Can this be transferred to Xamarin and used with MySQL and PHPMyAdmin

Comment: I would assume so. Some of the SQL may needed to be tweaked since the syntax is slightly different. At least this should give you something to work with. It does load onto the page context that is meant to display it.